# matching pairs of positive and negative numbers for every id

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the dataframe below:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'id': [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4],
    'amount':[2,3,5,-5,2,3,-5,3,4]}

d = pd.DataFrame(d)
d
   id   amount
0   1   2
1   1   3
2   2   5
3   2   -5
4   2   4
5   2   6
6   3   2
7   3   3
8   3   -5
9   4   3
10  4   4
11  4   100
12  4   -100
```

So what i want to do, is match the positive with the negative values per id and i do this:

```
d[d.groupby(['id'])['amount'].transform('sum').eq(0)
```

which gives me this output:

```
   id   amount
2   2   5
3   2   -5
4   3   2
5   3   3
6   3   -5
```

So as you can see my code does not only matches pairs of rows as i want. For instance, for id 3, it matches three rows on the condition i've set. How can i get it to only match pairs of rows and  have the  desired output as the one below:

```
   id   amount
2   2   5
3   2  -5
11  4   100
12  4  -100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to check if element's negative exists in its own group:

```
def refunded(data):
    return data[data["amount"].isin(-data["amount"])]

    new_df = df.groupby("id").apply(refunded).reset_index(0, drop=True)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
    id  amount
2    2       5
3    2      -5
11   4     100
12   4    -100
```

Comment: Thanks. So i have a dataframe with transactions ('amount') and users ('id) and i want to check if a positive transaction matches a negative one (essentially i want to find the transactions that are refunds). I ran your code  on my complete dataframe but it has missed a lot of the desired transactions.

Comment: I believe it missed out those with more than 2 rows? It would be better if you can update your sample in your question to provide an example ;). I guess `len` and `sum` invited too many race conditions (e.g. `[5, 5, -5, -5]`)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I updated  the sample df and my desired output. Every user_id  can have more than two rows-transactions.

Comment: @Unicorn07 Can you check my update?